# How can I add a submit button inside my texbox using angular material?

Tags: input, angular-material

I'm trying to add a 'send' button on the right side of my text input in angular material.

```html
<md-input-container> 
 <input type="text" style="bottom:0; width:90%; height: 15%; position: fixed; border-top: 1px solid black">
 <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" id="send" style="position:absolute;">Send</md-button>
</md-input-container>
```

But my send button doesn't appear close to my textbox. How can I get the button inside the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to separate things in your form is using the [layout containers](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container)

```
<div layout="row">
  <!-- Textbox -->
  <md-input-container> 
    <label>Name</label>
    <input ng-model="yourModelHere">
  </md-input-container>
  <!-- Send Button -->
  <md-input-container>
    <md-button id="send" class="md-raised md-primary">Send</md-button>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

**Result**

[image]

Keep rocking!